# serial COM port issue @ reading

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port, virtual, simulation

Here is the COM port opening part:

```
    portHandle=CreateFileA(portName, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (portHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    return -1;
}
COMMCONFIG Win_CommConfig;
COMMTIMEOUTS Win_CommTimeouts;
unsigned long confSize = sizeof(COMMCONFIG);
Win_CommConfig.dwSize = confSize;
GetCommConfig(portHandle, &Win_CommConfig, &confSize);
Win_CommConfig.dcb.Parity = 0;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fNull=FALSE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = FALSE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fInX=FALSE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fOutX=FALSE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.fBinary=TRUE;
Win_CommConfig.dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
if (baudrate != -1)
{
    Win_CommConfig.dcb.BaudRate = baudrate;
}
Win_CommConfig.dcb.ByteSize = 8;
Win_CommTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
Win_CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
Win_CommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 110;
Win_CommTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
Win_CommTimeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 110;
SetCommConfig(portHandle, &Win_CommConfig, sizeof(COMMCONFIG));
SetCommTimeouts(portHandle,&Win_CommTimeouts);
return 0;
```

It connects OK, I manage to issue some AT comamnds and read back OK\n> responses, even one of the upper level protocol (OBD2: the command is `0100\r`) gets a proper answer. But when I attempt other commands such as scanning of supported pids (e.g `0000\n`, `0101\n`, `0202\n` etc) the whole thing either echoes back whatever I write to it or just times out. Issuing the same sequence of commands from a hyperterminal works properly. These serial ports are virtual simulated ports should it matter - http://com0com.sourceforge.net/.
What am I missing ? Perhaps some reading / setting / resetting of someof the pins ? It has been a while since I last mingled with RS232... Thanks!

EDIT: just tried the scantool at https://www.scantool.net/downloads/diagnostic-software/ and it worked ok too.

Answer (score 0):

> e.g 0000\n, 0101\n, 0202\n

This was the issue. It should have been \r at the end, not \n. Hyperterminal worked because the  key would insert a \r here on Windows. Probablysome validation of the input was done by the device connected and so it  got to work even with the wrong terminator character fed in.